# Gmail asking for authentication after changing SIMs

Tags: sim-card, google-account, google-authenticator

To recreate issue:

1. Start 2-factor authentication
2. Generate app-specific code
3. Use that to sign into your device
4. Change the SIM

I have two SIMs, and I sometimes switch between them. The issue is that once I do so, it prompts for the password. I then have to create a new app-specific password using my computer to access GMail.

Is there any way to fix this bug? If so, how can I do it?

I appreciate any help.

Note: This question is not a duplicate, as all the other apps are working, I have multi-factor authentication and